# How do I provide a container for popover component?

Tags: reactjs

I decided to use react-simple-popover for my popover needs. Documentation is here: https://github.com/dbtek/react-popover. The problem is that the documentation is for stateful components (class components). The `container` prop takes in `this` of the current class component, but I am using stateless component with hooks. What do I pass in place of the "this" keyword in this way?

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Popover from "react-simple-popover";
import { HelpQuestion } from "../UI/Common";

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
`;

export const TextInput = styled.input`
  border: 1px solid
    ${(props) => (props.dark ? "#37394B" : props.theme.lightGray)};
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: ${(props) => (props.dark ? "white" : "black")};
  background-color: ${(props) => (props.dark ? "#37394B" : "white")};
`;



export default function TextField({
  label,
  value,
  onChange,
  onClick,
  error,
  type,
  placeholder,
  help,
  dark,
  disabled,
}) {
  const [isPopoverOpen, setPopoverOpen] = useState(false);
  const popoverRef = useRef(null);
  const componentRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <Wrapper ref={componentRef}>
  
      <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <TextInput
          value={value}
          onChange={!disabled ? onChange : () => {}}
          onClick={onClick}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          type={type}
          dark={dark}
          disabled={disabled}
        />
        {help && (
          <div
            style={{ marginLeft: "0.5rem" }}
            onClick={() => setPopoverOpen(!isPopoverOpen)}
            ref={popoverRef}
          >
            <HelpQuestion className="fas fa-question" />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      {error && <Error>{error}</Error>}
      <Popover
        placement="left"
        container={componentRef.current} //doesnt work
        target={popoverRef}
        show={isPopoverOpen}
        onHide={() => setPopoverOpen(false)}
      >
        <p>{help}</p>
      </Popover>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I provide a container for popover component?
>
> What do I pass in place of the "this" keyword in this way?

No, I don't think you can. View the [source](https://github.com/dbtek/react-popover/blob/master/src/Popover.js#L96-L100).

```
const Popover = props => {
  if (
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(props.container) &&
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(props.container).parentElement.parentElement !==
      document.body
  ) {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(props.container).style.position = 'relative';
  }
  return (
    <Overlay
      show={props.show}
      onHide={props.onHide}
      placement={props.placement}
      container={props.container}
      target={p => ReactDOM.findDOMNode(props.target)}
      rootClose={props.hideWithOutsideClick}
    >
      <PopoverContent
        showArrow={props.showArrow}
        arrowStyle={props.arrowStyle}
        innerStyle={props.style}
        style={props.containerStyle}
      >
        {props.children}
      </PopoverContent>
    </Overlay>
  );
};
```

It doesn't appear to be well maintained and it's using `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` which is practically deprecated. I tried [this](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/issues/105) and also tried a small class-based component wrapper. Nothing worked. Each time the reported error referred to the current ref value (`componentRef.current`) not being a react component.

For what its worth I suggest using a more functional component friendly `Popover` component. Here's an example using Material-UI's [Popover](https://material-ui.com/components/popover/) component.

```
function TextField({
  label,
  value,
  onChange,
  onClick,
  error,
  type,
  placeholder,
  help,
  dark,
  disabled
}) {
  const [isPopoverOpen, setPopoverOpen] = useState(false);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  const clickHandler = (e) => {
    setPopoverOpen((open) => !open);
    setAnchorEl(e.target);
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <TextInput
          value={value}
          onChange={!disabled ? onChange : () => {}}
          onClick={onClick}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          type={type}
          dark={dark}
          disabled={disabled}
        />
        {help && (
          <div style={{ marginLeft: "0.5rem" }} onClick={clickHandler}>
            <HelpOutlineIcon />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      {error && <Error>{error}</Error>}
      <Popover
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={isPopoverOpen}
        onClose={() => setPopoverOpen(false)}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "center",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: "center",
          horizontal: "right"
        }}
      >
        <p>{help}</p>
      </Popover>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-do-i-provide-a-container-for-popover-component]